# Disabling home button in android while running an async task

Tags: android

I need to make disable or inactive the home button of my android phone while running the async task created by me. Please see the error logs i am getting while interrupting the async task.

```
01-01 01:09:39.375: ERROR/WindowManager(1415): Activity  com.android.settings.ThemePreview has leaked window  com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView@418cb518 that was originally added here
01-01 01:09:39.375: ERROR/WindowManager(1415): android.view.WindowLeaked: Activity com.android.settings.ThemePreview has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView@418cb518 that was originally added here
01-01 01:09:39.375: ERROR/WindowManager(1415):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.<init>(ViewRootImpl.java:350)
01-01 01:09:39.375: ERROR/WindowManager(1415):     at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:245)
01-01 01:09:39.375: ERROR/WindowManager(1415):     at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:193)
01-01 01:09:39.375: ERROR/WindowManager(1415):     at android.view.WindowManagerImpl$CompatModeWrapper.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:118)
01-01 01:09:39.375: ERROR/WindowManager(1415):     at android.view.Window$LocalWindowManager.addView(Window.java:537)
01-01 01:09:39.375: ERROR/WindowManager(1415):     at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:279)
01-01 01:09:39.375: ERROR/WindowManager(1415):     at com.android.settings.ThemePreview$ApplyTheme.onPreExecute(ThemePreview.java:357)
01-01 01:09:39.375: ERROR/WindowManager(1415):     at android.os.AsyncTask.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.java:561)
01-01 01:09:39.375: ERROR/WindowManager(1415):     at android.os.AsyncTask.execute(AsyncTask.java:511)
01-01 01:09:39.375: ERROR/WindowManager(1415):     at com.android.settings.ThemePreview.onOptionsItemSelected(ThemePreview.java:239)
01-01 01:09:39.375: ERROR/WindowManager(1415):     at android.app.Activity.onMenuItemSelected(Activity.java:2502)
01-01 01:09:39.375: ERROR/WindowManager(1415):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.onMenuItemSelected(PhoneWindow.java:961)
01-01 01:09:39.375: ERROR/WindowManager(1415):     at com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuBuilder.dispatchMenuItemSelected(MenuBuilder.java:735)
01-01 01:09:39.375: ERROR/WindowManager(1415):     at com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuItemImpl.invoke(MenuItemImpl.java:149)
01-01 01:09:39.375: ERROR/WindowManager(1415):     at com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuBuilder.performItemAction(MenuBuilder.java:874)
01-01 01:09:39.375: ERROR/WindowManager(1415):     at com.android.internal.view.menu.ActionMenuView.invokeItem(ActionMenuView.java:490)
01-01 01:09:39.375: ERROR/WindowManager(1415):     at com.android.internal.view.menu.ActionMenuItemView.onClick(ActionMenuItemView.java:103)
01-01 01:09:39.375: ERROR/WindowManager(1415):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:3480)
01-01 01:09:39.375: ERROR/WindowManager(1415):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:13993)
01-01 01:09:39.375: ERROR/WindowManager(1415):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605)
01-01 01:09:39.375: ERROR/WindowManager(1415):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
01-01 01:09:39.375: ERROR/WindowManager(1415):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
01-01 01:09:39.375: ERROR/WindowManager(1415):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4368)
01-01 01:09:39.375: ERROR/WindowManager(1415):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-01 01:09:39.375: ERROR/WindowManager(1415):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
01-01 01:09:39.375: ERROR/WindowManager(1415):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
01-01 01:09:39.375: ERROR/WindowManager(1415):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
01-01 01:09:39.375: ERROR/WindowManager(1415):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: That sounds like a terrible idea. Changing menu/back/search button functionality makes sense in some contexts, but don't mess with home.

Comment: Many malicious coders also want that. If Google gives you the ability, they would get it also. Share why do you want that kind of feature. There should be very good practices to handle similar situations gracefully

Comment: This application is to applying the new theme. In my async task i am storing the icons of the theme resources into the database. If the user presses the home button in between then the task wont complete and the icons of the theme are not changing.

Comment: @Paru: As Sarwar Erfan says, you need to write code which gracefully handles interruptions such as the user pressing the HOME button. You should also present some sort of 'progress' indicator that shows the user that something is happening. By doing that then you will hopefully have fewer users pressing HOME if they think something is going on. Also, remember there are other things which may interrupt your Activity such as an incoming phone call...are you intending to block incoming phone calls while your AsyncTask completes? That wouldn't be good coding.

Comment: you need to handle the onPause() and onResume() here. Check in onResume(), if you have the new theme icons and then apply them

Comment: Added the error log i am getting while interrupting the async task

Comment: This is happening most probably because you are trying to make changes to the UI from Asynctask's onPostExecute() ( or a handler) while the activity has stopped. You need to check whether activity is in foreground before making UI changes from asynctask.

Comment: post you Activity's code if u need more help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Home button **cannot** be disabled. It is part of the **security principle** of android that the user should be able to minimise app and go to home screen anytime. It is also essential as Android ia multi-tasking. You need to change your logic to suit that. Personally, I wouldn't trust an app. which doesnt let me go to the home screen and start an app of my choice.

Comment: It also breaks the UX design and upsets users. You are essentially creating fragmentation by doing this

Comment: @jjNford - you are right. As a user, I would be pretty upset if the home button suddenly starts working.

Answer (score 0):

So we can't disable Home button.
In Android SDK whenever we press HOME key, app minimises and launches Home screen.
So we can't have any event related to Home Key.

Answer (score 0):

use this override method  below in your activity:

```
@Override
public void onAttachedToWindow()
{  
       this.getWindow().setType(WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_KEYGUARD);     
       super.onAttachedToWindow();  
}
```